# AdLockOptimistic equivalent in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm working on a .Net Razor Web Page and I want to know how to block the read registry (previously I used AdLockOptimistic in ADO) until the update is completed, my code is...

```
        var sqlLeeUsr = "SELECT UsrSmlla FROM tbUsr WHERE (UsrNro=@0)";
        var usr = db.QuerySingle(sqlLeeUsr, intUsrNro);
        if (usr != null)
        {
            intSecuencia = usr.UsrSmlla + 1;

            var sqlModUsr = "UPDATE tbUsr SET UsrSmlla=@0 FROM tbUsr WHERE (UsrNro=@1)";
            db.Execute(sqlModUsr, intSecuencia, intUsrNro);
        }
```

Comment: `I want to know how to block the read registry (previously I used AdLockOptimistic in ADO) ` I don't understand what you mean by this. What is the 'registry' in this context? What does your code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: I only want manage the concurrency in the table tbUsr. I take the last sequence (UsrSmlla) from this table (tbUsr), then I add 1 to this sequence and I keep it in
intSecuencia, at last I update the field UsrSmlla with the value in intSecuencia. I want no one else to be able to access the same registry while the previous process is completed.

Comment: Please see AdLockOptimistic in... https://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_rs_locktype.asp

Comment: What you need to do is something like `UPDATE tbUsr SET UsrSmlla=UsrSmlla+1 FROM tbUsr OUTPUT INSERTED.UsrSmlla WHERE (UsrNro=@1)` - this will increment the value and return the new (incremented) value in a single SQL statement. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/156604/

Comment: Yes, I want to lock the last sequence such that no-one else can read from it until I write the new value. Please say me how can I do that in a Razor cshtml Web Page.

Comment: Thank's for your last answer i will try this.

Comment: I would also suggest you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/types-of-locks#adlockoptimistic . I suspect your understanding of `adLockOptimistic` is not 100% correct.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your attention, your solution work fine.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Rather than querying the value, **then** incrementing it, you should do the two operations in one. That way, each invocation will **definitely** get a unique value.

The code you want to execute is likely:

```
var sqlLeeUsr = "UPDATE tbUsr SET UsrSmlla=UsrSmlla+1
    FROM tbUsr
    OUTPUT INSERTED.UsrSmlla
    WHERE (UsrNro=@1)";
var changed = db.QuerySingle(sqlLeeUsr, intUsrNro);
```

*This will update the table and return the new (incremented) value.*